# Strange Allowed Apex Syntax

Tags: apex, bug

Found some crazy apex syntax and I have no clue what it does.

```
public Account<List<String<Contact>>> whatIsWrongWithApex;
```

Is this a defect?  Should this do something?  Compiler not strict enough?

For the sake of the question, here is a simpler example:

```
public String<String> iThoughtThisShouldOnlyWorkForCollections;
```

Edit: Here is a full example where I instantiate an Account using this method and successfully insert it into the database:

```
public class ABug {
  public Account<List<String<Contact>>> whatIsWrongWithApex;

  public ABug() {
    whatIsWrongWithApex = new Account<List<String<Contact>>>();
    whatIsWrongWithApex.Name = 'Account Name';
    insert whatIsWrongWithApex;
  }
}
```

Anonymous Apex:

```
new ABug();
```

Comment: what happens when you run the code? even if it compiles  what is the result?

Comment: It compiles.  In the case of `public Account<List<String<Contact>>> whatIsWrongWithApex;` it works no different than `public Account whatIsWrongWithApex;` as far as I can tell.  I am wondering if it serves any other purpose.

Comment: This is crazy, do you know who wrote the code? (and why) I wouldn't call it a bug, but a hole in the compiler checking as you said. If @RichUnger still visits this site he should be able to give an answer

Comment: Can you actually instantiate any of them with anything other than the top level type? I could only ever use `new Account();` in the first example.

Comment: You can't instantiate the second one.  The compiler error is 'type cannot be instatiated'.

Comment: You're right bob, but that's only because you can't ever instantiate a String via new in Apex.  You can still do `iThoughtThisShouldOnlyWorkForCollections  = 'a string';`

Comment: Based on this behavior, my guess is that type declarations for non-generic classes are simply ignored. Interesting, but not too severe.

Comment: Strange and interesting. I'm guessing it creates a single element String array (the string(string), not the list(string(contact)))). +1 on not too severe, since this speaks more to a gap in understanding or a typo than a trap many would fall into.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This 'strange' syntax is a result of native Java support for Generics.

We cannot leverage the power of generics in Apex just yet, but the platform itself most certainly does. This is likely being exposed here through the definition & inheritance of the sObject class.

[Java Generic Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html)